# What is the density function of a random variable $Y (ω) = φ (X (ω))$？

Tags: probability, random-variables

About statistics, random variables, and their transformations

There is the following proposition in a book.

Proposition:
 (Ω, Σ, P) is a probability space, X: Ω → R is a continuous random variable on  (Ω, Σ, P)  and its density function is f.
φ: R → R is a strictly monotonic function and we put φ^-1=h. Assume that φ is differentiable on R and φ ′ is continuous and  not  0 on R.
Y: Ω → R is defined as Y (ω) = φ (X (ω)). then, Y is a continuous random variable and the density function is
                          g (y) = f (h (y)) | h ′ (y) |

Is this proposition true? In my opinion, this proposition is false. I think  the following two assumptions should be added for the conclusion:
(1) f is continuous on R
(2) f (h (y)) | h ′ (y) | is bounded on φ (R)

In  the proof described in that book, the author seems to implicitly assume that (3) φ (R) = R, and I think (3) is a substitute for (2). However, in this case, (1) must still be added to the assumptions.

Comment: Why do you think we need the density to be continuous? As it turns out, all you need is that $f(h(y))|h'(y)|$ is *integrable*, which follows from the fact that $f$ is.

Comment: I think （1）is needed to prove that f (h (y)) | h ′ (y) | is integrable. Can this be proved without (1)？

Comment: I think the density function of Y is g(y) = f (h (y)) | h ′ (y) |  on φ (R) and 0 otherwise

Comment: Your last comment is a good point. And if $h$ is any injective $C^1$ map with never-vanishing derivative and $f$ is integrable, then $f(h(y))|h'(y)|$ will be integrable, no other assumptions on $f$ needed.

Comment: I didn't come up with that idea.  Is (2) needed?

Comment: Nope. There are integrable functions which are unbounded.